# Arrays are empty in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to grab the innerText from a div with a specific class, but when i console.log it, it shows me an empty array.

The problem is supposed to be here. I read that querySelector can't show text or something like that. I'm a beginner, so I can't figure it out.

```js
const jobs = [];

for (let enlace of jobPost) {
  await page.goto(enlace);
  await page.waitForSelector('[class="css-17x2pwl e11nt52q6"]')

  const eachJob = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const tmp = {};
    tmp.job = document.querySelectorAll('[class="css-17x2pwl e11nt52q6"]').innerText;
    tmp.company = document.querySelectorAll('[class="css-16nw49e e11nt52q1"]').innerText;
    return tmp;
  });
  jobs.push(eachJob);

}

console.log(jobs);

await browser.close();
```

[Result of console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2L09k.png)

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll` returns a list of nodes. You can't get `innerText` of it.

You should either iterate through its items

```
tmp.job = [];
document.querySelectorAll('[class="css-17x2pwl e11nt52q6"]')
   .forEach(item => tmp.job.push(item.innerText));
```

Or just get the first match with `querySelector`